# UIBarButtonItem change the icon fill to white ios

Tags: ios, ios7, styling, uiappearance

Hello I've been trying to figure out how to change the 'fill' which I believe is the tint color for a UIBarButtonItem but when I try to do it using either appearance or appearanceWhenContainedIn is not working keep giving me the icon as blue:

[image]

I wish it could be white, when I customize the the button itself I am able to change the tint color and it work, but I would like to do it with appearance for all my buttons. Here is the code where I do the styling, If someone can give me a hint or a tip how to do this kind of things?

```
-(void)applyStyle {

    [self styleUIButtons];


    UIImage *navigationBarBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"base_nav_bar" ] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance]setBackgroundImage:navigationBarBackground forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance]setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: self.mainNavigationBarTextColor}];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: self.mainNavigationBarTextColor} forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTitleColor:self.mainNavigationBarTextColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIImage* barButtonImage = [self createSolidColorImageWithColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.1] andSize:CGSizeMake(10, 10)];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:barButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setBackgroundImage:barButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTintColor:self.mainNavigationBarIconColor  ];


    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12], NSFontAttributeName,
                                [UIColor grayColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,

                                nil];
    [[UISegmentedControl appearance]setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];





}

-(UIImage*)createSolidColorImageWithColor:(UIColor*)color andSize:(CGSize)size{

    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, scale);

    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect fillRect = CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(currentContext, color.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(currentContext, fillRect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}

- (void) styleUIButtons {
    UIImage *buttonNormalBg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_normal" ] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
    UIImage *buttonSelectedBgb = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_selected" ] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];

    id appearance = [UIButton appearance];

    [appearance setTintColor:self.mainNavigationBarTextColor];
    [appearance setBackgroundImage:buttonNormalBg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [appearance setBackgroundImage:buttonSelectedBgb forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

Comment: When you say you want it to be white, do you mean the tree icon in the barbutton?

Comment: Yes, well it is actually white but the barbutton put it in blue

Comment: Take a look at the "Customizing Your App's Appearance for iOS 7" video from WWDC 2013. I don't know the exact answer to your question, but this video speaks about Navigationbars, UIToolbars, UITabBars and UIColor quite a bit.

Answer (score 10):

To keep original image color in your UIBarButtonItem on iOS 7, try to use **imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal** and set it as in code below:

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[buttonImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]
                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                             target:self
                                                             action:@selector(action:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

Comment: `UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];`   `[_barbuttonItem setImage : image];`